# Changing the default view path in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view, themes

I want to be able to change dynamically the view folder. The aim is to be able to change completely the web design  depending on the request. I am thinking about something like this :

```
 Class PagesController

     default_views_path(current_theme_path)

     def show
         Blablah...
     end

 end
```

Supposing a directory architecture like this :

```
 -apps
 --views
 ---theme 1/show.html.erb
 ---theme 2/show.html.erb
 ---theme 3/show.html.erb
```

I search over the web and I have found `preprend_view_path`. (:deprecated) Do you think this is a good idea ot use this ? Any feedback ?

EDIT

In fact, I want to simplify this :

```
 Class PagesController

     def show
         render "#{current_theme}/show"
     end

     def edit
         render "#{current_theme}/edit"
     end

     def list
         render "#{current_theme}/list"
     end

     def index
         render "#{current_theme}/index"
     end

 end
```

Any Solutions ?

Comment: what about layouts? Or partials? if request.somerequest, :render => 'something'

Comment: Hey! I'm looking for a part time rails/ruby job. If you have, you can consider me. I have my email id in my SO profile itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [append_view_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/append_view_path/class). In fact, there is a comment on this append_view_path page where someone has used it for theming.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `layout :some_method_to_change_theme` instead? This will simplify and will keep your views DRY.
 Look at this
[layout](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods/layout)

Comment: layout works only for changing the layout, but not for changing the yielded templates themselves. Still a good point to not forget that.